# google adwords api python app engine demo updated version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-ads-api

Does anyone know where can I download the latest non depracated version of the demo on this link:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/demo-apps#awapi_app_engine_python

also if no, I have the 4.3 version and I need to change the xml parser used because pyxml is no longer working.

Any Tips?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a good AdWords python client is the [googleads-python-lib](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib) which you can install with pip:

```
pip install adspygoogle
```

They  also provide some examples on how to use it on Github here: [googleads-python-lib examples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/tree/master/examples/adspygoogle/adwords/v201309)

Comment: I don't want the client library, I want to have a running of this demo version described in the URL above

Comment: oh ok sorry about that, I just updated my answer hope this helps!